# Selecting text in a SuSE shell

Tags: shell, opensuse, copy-paste

I have a problem. An application has spat a whole load of log text into a Shell window that needs to be captured. If we could skip passed the "probably shouldn't have had an application output it's stdout anywhere other than a log file", is there a tool/command that I can use to capture the program output?

Other than highlighting all of the text with a mouse and copying to a text file. There are 250,000 lines... :)

Comment: Can you run it again and redirect into a text file? `myprog > log.txt`

Comment: I think if I suggest that to the offending admin he might pop. I have since discovered a method of setting selection markers on the window with the right click menu. This way I can easily select the area of text I am interested in. Then copy and paste. Not a quick task, just getting in onto the clipboard seems to take 5 minutes! I'm interested to hear any other answers though, so I'm not answering my own question. There must be a better way!

Comment: The shell only executes commands. The window is a *terminal*. And it would help if you told us which terminal program you are using. From OpenSuSE I'm guessing it's KDE Konsole, which has *File - Save Output As*.

Comment: Many apologies, you are right grawity. I am using KDE Konsole... but I have no file menu option, I have; session, edit, view, bookmarks, settings, help. None of which have a save output, annoyingly.

Comment: @tigers: It must be a different Konsole version than the one I have (2.6.4, KDE 4.6.5). Can't offer any more suggestions :(

Comment: @tigers I understand that position that you are in, however, that is a reasonable way to get output from `stdout`.  The problem with the way you are approaching it is that you may hit the wall at the end of the backscroll buffer and not be able to get all of the data via select and copy anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can run the program again, you have 3 options:

1. If you don't need to see the output as the program runs, use simple redirection (as jonsca has already suggested) :

   > $ yourVerboseProgram > anyNameForYourLogFile
2. If you want to see the program's output as it runs, you have two (at least) options:

   a) Run it as described above, while in a second terminal running `tail -f yourLogFile`

   b) ('b' for 'better') Use `tee`:

   > $ yourVerboseProgram | tee anyNameForYourLogFile
3. If 2. applies **and the program is interactive** (needs your input as it runs), use the `script` program:

   ```
   $ script aLogFile.log
   Script started, file is aLogFile.log
   $ yourVerboseProgram
   ```

   (the program running... And exiting.) Then you exit the script:

   ```
   $ exit
   Script done, file is aLogFile.log
   ```

   The only problem with option 3 is that *everything* is being logged, including your keystrokes like pressing "Backspace" etc.